# Create a trigger to remove white space from one of the column in Oracle procedure not working

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

While creating Trigger, what I want is if the column is filled with values like below:

`This is my test comment to explain`

After the word "explain" there are some white spaces which I want to remove on `INSERT` or `UPDATE`. So below is the logic which I tried.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "APP_WFM"."VSAT_REMOVE_SPACES" 
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE "APP_WFM"."TBL_VSAT_MST_DETAIL" 
FOR EACH ROW 
   WHEN (NEW.HUGHES_REMARKS like '% ') EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.TrimRid();
END;
```

But it's giving me error as

> ORA-00969: missing ON keyword
> 00969. 00000 -  "missing ON keyword`

Here is table description:

```
Name                           Null     Type            
------------------------------ -------- --------------- 
VSAT_DETAIL_ID                 NOT NULL NUMBER(38)      
SAP_ID                         NOT NULL VARCHAR2(20)    
CANDIDATE_ID                   NOT NULL VARCHAR2(20)     
HUGHES_REMARKS                          CLOB            
RJIL_REMARKS                            CLOB            
CREATED_BY                              NVARCHAR2(100)  
CREATED_DATE                   NOT NULL DATE
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 2):

As the error says you are missing the `ON` keyword.

```
create or replace TRIGGER "APP_WFM"."VSAT_REMOVE_SPACES" 
 before insert OR UPDATE ON "APP_WFM"."TBL_VSAT_MST_DETAIL" 
                  -------^^
```

But you also have an invalid construction; you a `begin` with the actual work done inside that; `execute` is a client construct unless you're doing dynamic SQL; and you can't call something directly via the `public` role. You don't need an external procedure though, you can just trim the value here:

```
create or replace TRIGGER "APP_WFM"."VSAT_REMOVE_SPACES" 
  before insert OR UPDATE ON "APP_WFM"."TBL_VSAT_MST_DETAIL" 
  for each row 
  WHEN (NEW.HUGHES_REMARKS like '% ')
begin
  :new.HUGHES_REMARKS := RTRIM(:new.HUGHES_REMARKS);
end;
/
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=47c7266a07e31902100c7ebaba930b7b)

If you did really want to use a procedure then you would have to pass it `:new.HUGHES_REMARKS`, as a `IN OUT` argument - [like this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=f77f449978391fee09c716bb09c0710f). It would be an unnecessary complication though.

---

> it doesn't trim when there is multiple spaces. For ex: after space, user press 2 or 3 times enter key

[The `rtrim` function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/RTRIM.html) takes an option set of characters to trim, so you can do:

```
create or replace TRIGGER "APP_WFM"."VSAT_REMOVE_SPACES" 
  before insert OR UPDATE ON "APP_WFM"."TBL_VSAT_MST_DETAIL" 
  for each row 
  -- WHEN (NEW.HUGHES_REMARKS like '% ')
  WHEN (SUBSTR(NEW.HUGHES_REMARKS, -1, 1) IN (' ', chr(9), chr(10), chr(13)))
begin
  :new.HUGHES_REMARKS :=
    RTRIM(:new.HUGHES_REMARKS, ' '||chr(9)||chr(10)||chr(13));
end;
/
```

to remove spaces, tabs, newlines and carriage returns - and add any other characters you want.

I've also changed the `WHEN` to pick up cases where the last character isn't just a space.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=37203e58a9489f0347c5b1ce41a7329d)

You could use regular expressions to find and remove trailing whitespace, but those are generally more expensive and it's usually simpler and better to use other functions.

> Can we do it while inserting via procedure ? like this HUGHES_REMARKS  = P_HUGHES_REMARKS, ??

Yes, of course, just apply the `rtrim()` then:

```
RTRIM(P_HUGHES_REMARKS, ' '||chr(9)||chr(10)||chr(13))
```

Comment: it doesn't trim when there is multiple spaces. For ex: after space, user press 2 or 3 times enter key and then save it. then how to handle ?

Comment: @Nad - updated to remove other whitespace characters.

Comment: if u carefully see there is lot of space after `done.`

Comment: [The spaces at the end are removed.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=818a2a7500eb845d072b21bc1a74d75e). If you've got some other whitespace character there then you'll have to identify it and add it to the list in the `rtrim` call. You can't tell what it is once it's rendered as a comment.

Comment: Try this.  :new.HUGHES_REMARKS :=
REGEXP_REPLACE(:new.HUGHES_REMARKS, '\s{2,}', ' ')
 
This will replace two or more consecutive whitespace characters (spaces, tabs, etc.) with a single space. If you just want to replace spaces and not tabs, carriage returns, or newlines, use the following:
   
:new.HUGHES_REMARKS :=
REGEXP_REPLACE(:new.HUGHES_REMARKS, ' {2,}', ' ')

Comment: @AlexPoole: its that white space which gets copy pasted into textbox

Comment: maybe that trigger is not working, as its not removing the single  space also

Comment: @Nad - your `WHEN` clause meant it was only firing if the last character was a space; modified that to look for the same list of characters. If you end up with a value in the DB that doesn't seem to have been trimmed then `dump()` it to see what the last character is.

Comment: is the trigger working on insert or update. or its working on both ? Latest trigger is also not working

Comment: Can we do it while inserting via procedure ? like this `HUGHES_REMARKS  = P_HUGHES_REMARKS,` ??

Comment: Yes, just `rtrim` the variable instead. The trigger is working on insert and update, and you can see it working (albeit only on insert in the demo) in the fiddles in the answer; [added an update](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=d362cafa6ccc368f7a08f68c2abe25c1) to show that works too. No idea what you're doing differently - possibly using more than one schema?

Comment: @AlexPoole: can u come on chat here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245147/discussion-between-nad-and-thorsten-kettner